# User can access site without permissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, inheritance, site-settings

I have a problem with my SharePoint site.
I have created subsite with not inheritant permissions.

So I set number of users, but other user's can view items.
I see following when checking user permissions that should not be able to have access.

[image]

Thank you for your Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you stop inheriting permissions, the users with access remain to have access. You need to remove the users that are copied over from the parent.

Next to that option, some users have persmissions as a site collection admin, or on the web application level in Central Admin.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however when I created subsite I already specified it to have unique permissions. so When I check it's permissions nobody but my has access for example.

Comment: You were right I found in "user policy" of web application in Central Admin , windows usuer => full read. I removed it and voila :)

Comment: Don't change the Webapp permissions on a regular base. It will cause a full security crawl for the whole webapp.

Answer (score 1):

The permissions above are typical of someone in site collection admin. This person is on full control above the subsite you are talking about